# How can i send message to the socket which is in kestrel?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I have listened to two local ports through `kestrel` which are worked good.

```cs
webBuilder
    .UseKestrel(opt =>
    {
        // http request
        opt.ListenLocalhost(5000);
        // simple tcp communication with stm32-based device
        opt.Listen(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.2"), 501, opt =>
        {
            opt.UseConnectionHandler<MyTcpHandler>();
        });
    })
    .UseStartup<Startup>();
});
```

But how can I send message to the device connected with the specified ip(socket)

```cs
[HttPost("devices/{id}")]
public Task Send(int id, string msg)
{
    // convert id to ipendpoint
    var ipEndPoint = ipEndPoints[id];

    // get socket in kestrel by ipEndPoint 
    ??? 

    // send message
    socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(msg));
}
```

Comment: Please clarify what the end goal is - on an http(s) server, the connection is usually only there for the duration of a request.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server Error I want to control connected devices (long-lived TCP/IP connection) through http requests

Comment: What's on the other end sending those requests? If a browser, a web socket is your best (possibly only) option.

Comment: @500 - Internal Server probably can't. Those long-lived devices based on plc or arm.

Comment: Either you're doing HTTP (on top of TCP) or TCP, you can't do both.

Comment: Still can't send message to the specific socket if just use TCP.@davidfowl